# Java Controller what code to be in?

Tags: java, spring, controller

I am working on a Spring enabled web project where we have multiple controllers. Recently I had a discussion with senior developers what code should go in the controller.

Some of them said to make the controller light-weight; only invoking methods should go inside the controller. Even if there are only 3 lines of processing, make them separate methods and call them from the Controller as follows

```
public ModelAndView offersMapView(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {

Map<String, Object> contentMap = getServiceLocator().getHyperLocalService().getOffersHubContents(searchPostcode, gmapKey, ip);

            return getViewGenerator().generateOffersHubMapView(brand, contentMap);
}
```

Where generateOffersHubMapView(brand, contentMap) method contains only 2 line of code

```
public ModelAndView generateOffersHubMapView(Brand brand, Map<String, Object> contentMap) {     
        ModelAndView mv = POGAModelandView.createWebModelAndView(brand, WLConstants.__HUB_OFFERS);
        mv.addAllObjects(contentMap);       

        return mv;
    }
```

My point was that 2 lines creating separate view generator method is not good until we have number of lines of code processing.

The opposing point of view was creating separate method to keep segregation between layers.

Could I please ask the community what they think is the better approach? If possible, could you provide references to support your statements?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "until we have number of lines of code processing", but generally I'd say try not to think of usefulness of code in terms of how many lines it is... there is nothing wrong with having few lines of code in a separate method (in fact I'd argue it's generally better for readability than having long methods). Try to put code where you feel it "belongs", i.e. preserve encapsulation as much as you can (I know that can sometimes be hard to nail down in practice).

Comment: I got confused when reading those 2 lines, I guess you will feel the same if you read the code after a year. So, think readability for the least.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no rule which says that

```
 Even if there are only 3 lines of processing, make them separate methods
```

and I think splitting every three lines without a valid reason to do so will only complicate things . Concentrate on re-usability and readability . If you have reusable code in a single method, split it up. If you have a method which is too long and does a lot of things , split it up . Read the discussion at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20981/how-many-lines-of-code-is-too-many and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/903754/do-you-still-limit-line-length-in-code .

Personally I would say that generateOffersHubMapView method split does not make much sense in your sample .